# Share docker volumes from multiple hosts?

Tags: docker

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-28-named-volumes-vs-path-based-volumes

seems to suggest that both `named volumes` and `path based volumes` are stored in the docker host (where containers are run)

Suppose I have `web` and `nginx` service.

I thought I could run `web` service in one host and `nginx` in another host (two different machines) . 
(Although I'm just beginning to learn basics of docker, and it'll be a long time before I could separate services to different hosts)

Is there a way for `nginx` container to serve static files that `web` service has by sharing volumes between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker doesn't have a built in software based solution to share volumes across multiple machines yet. There's work on [infinit](https://blog.docker.com/2016/12/docker-acquires-infinit/) but they haven't released anything for production usage.

There are 3rd party storage solutions, that you can use. If you're on a cloud provider, their solution is typically the best for your use case. For a self hosted software solution, you could use something like glusterfs. Applications that handle data replication themselves are idea for containers, e.g. cockroachdb.

The typical self-hosted solution is to fall back on to NFS. Even with cloud providers, I typically use their NFS method to mount the storage. From docker, this looks like the following:

```
  # create a reusable volume
  $ docker volume create --driver local \
      --opt type=nfs \
      --opt o=nfsvers=4,addr=192.168.1.1,rw \
      --opt device=:/path/to/dir \
      foo

  # or from the docker run command
  $ docker run -it --rm \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,\"volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=192.168.1.1\",volume-opt=device=:/host/path \
    foo

  # or to create a service
  $ docker service create \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,\"volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=192.168.1.1\",volume-opt=device=:/host/path \
    foo

  # or inside a docker-compose file
  ...
  volumes:
    nfs-data:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: nfsvers=4,addr=192.168.1.1,rw
        device: ":/path/to/dir"
  ...
```

Note that the IP addresses in each of those can be hostnames as long as you keep the type of nfs.

Answer (score 0):

If your docker containers are running on the same host, then this is very easy. You just (as part of the `run` in my example, but could be created standalone) create a volume and mount it on both containers.

```
# Create a volume /data in a new container
$ docker run \
  -v /data \
  -it \
  --name mycontainer \
  ubuntu \
  /bin/bash
root@435cb561e0eb:/# touch /data/test
```

Then in another shell I start another ubuntu container (doesn't have to be ubuntu, could be a different image):

```
# Mount the same volume in another container
$ docker run \
  --volumes-from mycontainer \
  -it \
  ubuntu \
  /bin/bash
root@de70d474df7a:/# ls /data/
test
```

Then you just need to make sure that the web part of your application uses that mount (`/data` in this case) to store the data that you need to be shared between the two hosts.

As for between multiple hosts. Docker doesn't do that, but could build on top of NFS or something to achieve that.