# Docker image that is pulled doesn't contained the files

Tags: docker

I have the following container webbased file browser, files that are uploaded are stored in ('/01_VOL1:/srv') i successfully commit the changes , tag and push the image to dockerhub registry. when i pull the same image on to the new server with docker. everything else works fine but there are no  files in it. how can i preserve the files from every commit and push?

What am i doing wrong?

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    filebrowser:
        container_name: browser
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '8086:80'
        volumes:
            - '/01_VOL1:/srv'
        environment:
            - TZ=Asia/Qatar
        image: 'xxxxxdocker/xxxrepo:browser_v1'
```

Comment: hard to say. can you post which command you use to start the container, build the image etc?

Comment: If the uploaded files are stored in the `/srv` directory, then the files are stored outside the container filesystem and aren't persisted when you commit the new image.

Comment: Ok, you are using volumes. You need to share this volumes between hosts. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076644/share-docker-volumes-from-multiple-hosts

Comment: "I ran some commands and committed the result" is not a reproducible way to create an image; in most cases you should never use `docker commit`.  Do you have a `Dockerfile` or another reproducible recipe to create your image?  (See for example Docker's [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial.)\